# dSYM files not available on iTunes/App Store Connect (bitcode enabled)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bitcode, dsym

Our application has bitcode enabled, so we can't use dSYM files generated on our machines/CI but rather we should use dSYM generated during bitcode compilation. The problem here is that we don't have those files available to download on App Store Connect (no link is presented).

[image: No "Download dSYM" link available]

That's really weird. We suspected that maybe our 3rd party tool which we upgraded recently and that is used to obfuscate our binaries started to work incorrectly but all builds get "Validated" status and we can publish them in App Store without any issue.

I suppose that bitcode process runs correctly as we get smaller binaries available in App Store, but dSYM is somehow not produced.

I found a thread on Apple Developer Forums but nothing really uncovers the root of this issue: [DSYMs No Longer Offered for Download?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/353115)

Comment: Why do you need `dSYM`? Are the crash reports not symbolicated?

Comment: Yes. We symbolicate them on Fabric, but we are not able to get them from iTunes Connect. The process worked fine few weeks ago, we discovered that it stopped working because we start getting more unsymbolicated crashlogs.

Comment: You are obfuscating your binary with a third-party too and asking why you don't get symbols? When you upload to the app-store via archiving, it asks you to check the box to also upload symbols.. Did you do that?

Comment: We use fastlane pilot to upload to iTunes. We didn’t change this script.

Comment: I tried to compile bitcode locally to have some view how it could be processed on the iTunes side and I was able to generate dSYM from compiled bitcode: xcrun ipatool --compile-bitcode Obfuscated.ipa -o recompiled